# Overheating on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: overheating

I have dell inspiron q17r with two graphic cards and I noticed that it is overheating. I installed bumblebee, jupiter and flashblock, I followed this: http://techhamlet.com/2012/05/ubuntu-how-to-fix-over-heating-of-laptops-with-switchable-graphics/ and right now my laptop temperature is 64C. Is there anything more I can do? Because it still doesn't reallly seem to be working well. Fan is going really fast..

Comment: you might have better luck getting an answer to this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: ok, ill try there.

Comment: Is it hotter than a iMac?

Comment: Ok, so I found something.
It is heating because of "pci=noacpi". But without it I can't run Ubuntu ( only a purple screen appears while loading and that's it ).
So..Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your computer does not have ACPI fan control enabled. Try booting with acpi=ht, acpi=noirq, pnpacpi=off, noapic, and nolapic (one at a time) and see if any of those work. Does your computer still overheat with those parameters? If so, you may want to consider using a [cooling pad](http://www.restockit.com/cooler-master-usa-x-slim-notepal-cooler-%28r9nbcxsligp%29.html).